# Way to run multiple commands at once without multithreading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm looking to run a second process at the same time as another is running. I know multithreading exists, but was wondering if that's the only way to do multiple things at once in Python?

eg. runnning something:

```
import time, random

number = random.randint(0, 100)

while True:
  user_input = input("Enter a number: ")
  if user_input == number:
     print("Congratulations")
     quit()
```

At the same time as:

```
time.sleep(100)
print("Too slow")
quit()
```

Is running.

I've seen a very similar problem to this solved with threading, but wanted to know if there are other ways to do this in Python?

Comment: Yes, there are other ways, such as cooperative multitasking, to make it *appear* that two calculations are running simultaneously. But the code to do that is much more complicated. Do you want to limit your question to only what you show? That can be done in other ways, but you would need to drop the `time.sleep` and `input` lines and accomplish the same thing in another way.

Comment: I would suggest the async module. It's not quite doing multiple things at once but you can await functions at the same time, and rather than like with time.sleep which is what is known as "blocking" (locks the interpreter for example) and so no more code can be executed until the sleep timer has expired. Async differs I  such that you can await multiple commands but also execute multiple commands too. You don't have to worry about complex multithreading classes as anything like that is handled for you.

Comment: To solve this problem  in particular I suggest using the [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) class.